# QMediaPlayer not starting playback on Windows when started outside QtCreator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mp3, dll

I wanted to accommodate myself with Qt5 and so I started a very small mp3 player. It compiles on Linux and Windows 7, both 64 bit.

When running on Windows however the selected mp3 file will only start playing when I start the program within QtCreator. When I start the standalone (shared compiled) EXE the program opens but instead starting the playback nothing happens (when debugging inside the IDE everything seems to work, sort of a Heisenbug I guess).

When looking at the file access in *Processmonitor* I see the directory scan, however when the MP3 should be opened nothing happens.

Maybe I missed to copy a DLL, however I have no hint which one is missing, so it may be another issue. *Dependency Walker* output (though it does not tell me which files/funcionts cause the errors, maybe I missed it):

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

This is my directory content from where I try to start the EXE

- folder "platforms" including: qminimal.dll, qwindows.dll
- icudt49.dll, icuin49.dll, icuuc.49.dll
- IEShims.dll (works without it, however Dependency Walker told its missing)
- libEGL.dll
- libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Multimedia.dll, Qt5Network.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll
- purr.exe

You can look at the complete source @ https://github.com/VashSan/purr - part of the source code where i start the playback:

```
void PurrWindow::playMedia()
{
    // [...]
    // QMediaPlayer is a member of PurrWindow:

    QUrl media = QUrl::fromLocalFile(selectedFile);
    player.setMedia(media);
    player.play();
}
```

I compiled the program once with MSVC2010 and once with Mingw with no difference.

I tried to google QMediaPlayer errors but most of them concern mobile platforms. However it did not leave a good impression of the QMediaPlayer to me, maybe I should look at a more reliable playback library. However if it would just start playback I'd be happy.

Comment: Does Qt show `selectedFile` show as accessible (i.e., exists and readable)?

Comment: It's working both cases on my computer with Qt5 msvc2010

Comment: @Vash Please review the answers carefully, and up vote the ones that helped you. You can also click on the checkbox near an answer to select it as the official answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to find out if your **.exe** is referring to the right **.dlls**.

Sometimes people have more than one Qt/Phonon version installed and the `PATH` environment variable doesn't point to the directories where those DLLs are located.

Also, make sure `selectedFile` has the full path to the file. It's a good idea to **check if the path is valid** after:

```
selectedFile = fileDialog.getSelectedPath();
```

with:

```
QFile file( selectedFile );
if( !file.exists() )
{
  qDebug() << "!!! Invalid file: " << selectedFile;
  return;
}
```

Comment: I think it is missing the backend plugin for phonon. Because if the compile time linked dll is not in path, the exe just won't run, which is not the case. But for runtime loaded plugins, you won't be able to see it using dll export viewer.

Comment: @MinLin thanks for the hint: I had a close look to all DLLs that failed to load with process monitor Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll, Qt5OpenGL.dll, D3DCompiler_43.dll. now it works. Is there no other way to find out which DLLs are actaully needed if you do not want to supply all DLLs? Unfortunately there is no "Qt Runtime" one could be redirected to if something is missing :|

Comment: One way to find it is that you run it in QtCreator, play the music to make any runtime loaded dll ready. Then use the tool listdlls (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) to see what dlls are loaded by the exe. It will show all the dlls loaded.